# why events in vuetify calendar wasn't be shown?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I started using Vuetify Calendar, after adding it to my application we can only show the default view (month), the events was not shown also, when we open chrome console we see this problem: [see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMDjS.png)

Comment: Can you please provide us some code ?

Comment: i use the one used in vuetify : https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/master/packages/docs/src/examples/calendars/complex/events.vue

Comment: the problem was here  https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/c2734d3e7721ad794de84c89ce0486869580742c/packages/docs/src/examples/calendars/complex/events.vue#L164

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to update version of vuetify